# Ограничить возможности стороннего класса C#

Tags: c#, классы, модульность, песочница

Имеется (модульное) игровое приложение - арена, в нем реализован абстрактный класс (или интерфейс) для игрока. Игроков (игровые ИИ) наследуют от указанного класса и разрабатывают сторонние разработчики и предоставляют в виде скомпилированного dll.
Есть ли вообще возможность ограничить возможности этой сторонней dll? Ну, например защититься от "FORMAT C:" или от пересылки данных по сети, чтения с диска и т. д.
Пусть даже этот класс падает в этом случае - тогда игроку просто засчитывается техническое поражение.

Какой день бьюсь, но, хоть убейте, никак не пойму, как заставить это работать.
Как сделать чтобы все сторонние игроки работали в песочнице? Сейчас есть примерно такой код:

```
static class PlayersHost
{
    static public List<IPlayer> Players;

    static public void LoadPlayers()
    {
        Players = new List<IPlayer>();

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Players"), "*.dll");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                var types = asm.GetTypes();
                foreach (var type in types)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IPlayer player = (IPlayer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                        players.Add(player);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Потом я просто при старте приложения загружаю всех игроков:

```
PlayersHost.LoadPlayers();
```

и пользуюсь полученной коллекцией, например:

```
var player = PlayersHost.Players[0];
try { player.PrepareToPlay(); } catch { }
```

Нужно решение с использованием `AppDomain`

Comment: `new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution).PermitOnly()`

Comment: Добавлен конкурс, а зачем? Что вы, человек, назначивший награду,  хотели бы услышать в ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Готовое решение с использованием AppDomain, желательно с наименьшими затратами и чтобы имеющийся код не сильно пострадал.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для изолирования частично доверенного кода в .NET предусмотрен механизм ограничения доступа в рамках AppDomain - это называется Sandbox (запуск в песочнице).

```
AppDomain.CreateDomain( string friendlyName,
                        Evidence securityInfo,
                        AppDomainSetup info,
                        PermissionSet grantSet,
                        params StrongName[] fullTrustAssemblies);
```

Информация о том, как его использовать, а также ряд дополнительных соображений и нюансов подробно описаны в этой статье на MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ну кстати домены еще и для динамической загрузки и выгрузки этих DLL будут более чем полезны. Только думаю стоит дополнить ответ: классы которые должны быть использованы в отдельном домене из основного, должны наследоваться от `MarshalByRefObject`

Answer (score 11):

Альтернативным, более высокоуровневым решением может быть использование `System.AddIn`. Это фреймворк, более сложный, чем использование `AppDomain`, но он предоставляет больше возможностей. В частности, он позволяет автоматически находить загруженные add-in'ы, и загружать их по вашему желанию

- в текущий `AppDomain`
- в отдельный, специальный `AppDomain` для компонент, которым вы не доверяете
- каждую компоненту в отдельный `AppDomain`
- в отдельный внешний процесс
- каждую компоненту в отдельный `AppDomain` общего внешнего процесса.

При этом протокол взаимодействия остаётся тем же самым. При этом объекты, которые переходят через границу между основным кодом и add-in'ами, должны быть сериализуемыми.

К сожалению, полновесный пример не вписывается в формат ответа, но хороший пример есть в документации:

1. [Add-in overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200(v=vs.90).aspx)
2. [Walkthrough: Creating an Extensible Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788290(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: MAF и MEF - две стороны одной медали, MEF легче, но менее гибкий, MAF гибкий, функциональный и ужасно громоздкий. Хотя дополнительной работы хватает в обоих случаях

Comment: для сравнения https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rdorn: MEF само по себе вроде бы только для доверенных плагинов, кажется? Но по вашей ссылке написано, что они с MAF дружат.

Comment: не, не только, можно и недоверенные и как угодно. А если нужна динамическая загрузка-выгрузка плагинов, то только в отдельный домен грузить. Я и не писал что они не дружат =)

Comment: @rdorn: Ого, то есть MEF умеет урезать права плагину?

Comment: на самом деле механизм доменов к возможностям MEF и MAF просто прилагается сбоку, поэтому все что можно сделать на доменах, можно сделать и там и там. Единственное - не уверен что MEF умеет процессы дружить между собой, но тут уж ой, не пробовал