# Как использовать плагины и подключать файлы исполняемого кода?

Tags: c#, .net

Возникла необходимость в создании разных способов расшифровки данных.

Из системы приходят данные, а пользователю нужно выбрать (например в комбобоксе) "плагин" для расшифровки этих данных. Наприме, все эти "плагины" будут лежать в папке plugins вместе с файлами приложения.

Хочу использовать .cs файлы, чтобы пользователи могли редактировать или создавать свои "плагины" для расшифровки.

Был ранее проект, но там я пользовался уже готовой библиотекой и готовой структурой плагина (вот начало его):

```
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("PSMS_v1.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
namespace Plugins {
[Table(Name = "PSMS_v1.1")]
public class EventPlugin : Plugins.IEventPlugin {
    public static event Plugins.AddToArrayEventHandler AddToArray;
    public const int MinArraySize = 8;


    byte[] Array;
    private int _arrcount;
    public EventPlugin() {
        Array = new byte[0];

    }

    public EventPlugin(int arrcount, byte[] array) {
        _arrcount = arrcount;
        Array = array;
        if (Array.Length < MinArraySize) {
            _status = Category.ArrayError;
        }
        if (((Array[0] == 0x00) && ((Array[1] & 0x01) == 0x01)) ||
            ((Array[0] == 0x03) && ((Array[1] & 0x03) != 0))) {   // Если байт 1 содержит в первом бите признак "продолжения"...
            AddToArray(ref Array, 8); // В массив необходимо добавить 8 байт
            if (Array.Length < MinArraySize) {
                _status = Category.ArrayError;
            }
        }
    }
```

Но вот как использовать его и подключать к своему приложения, непонятно, а исходников нет(

Поделитесь пожалуйста информацией (ссылками/туториалами) на реализацию подобно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ограничить возможности стороннего класса C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578341/%d0%9e%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-c)

Comment: @АндрейNOP обновил вопрос

Comment: [тыц](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/449a6e3f-74ac-4239-adde-a41d2ef63365/-?forum=fordesktopru)